# Chemistry of adding maple syrup to marinade

Tags: venison, game

Game recipe calls for olive oil, ginger, garlic, balsamic vinegar, Worchestershire....and a tiny bit of Maple syrup.

Not enough for glazing.

Why add the maple syrup?

Comment: To add a subtle taste of maple syrup? Why do you assume the answer involves chemistry?

Comment: @Sneftel, isn't changing the taste about chemistry? ie: volatile compounds in food. which would mean that you've answered the question :)

Answer (score 5):

To add sweetness and the taste of maple to the marinade, of course.  Many marinades have some form of sugar in them.

Comment: Added sugars also contribute to caramelization during cooking!